# Where to set PGOPTS variable in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, environment-variables, centos-7, postgresql

I am using Postgresql 10 and after the installation of the database I placed `PGOPTS="-i"` inside this file `/etc/sysconfig/pgsql/postgresql` so that Postgresql would listen in all interfaces.

When I was using CentOS 6, this worked and the postgresql started with the `-i` option in the command line.

However, I needed to migrate the database to CentOS 7 and postgresql (now it started using `postmaster` instead of `postgres`) doesn't startup with the option.

I know that in EL7, `systemd` is used and the file in the sysconfig directory might not be read. But then, where can I set this variable?

I am also looking at setting this variable as a new file. As I am using Ansible, it is a requirement for me to have a new file with this configuration. This means I don't want to edit existing files like `postgres.conf` placed in the database installation directory. This would be only done, if there isn't any other option of setting the PGOPTS variable somewhere.

I have tried:

- `/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service.d/postgresql.conf` with the following inside the `[Service]` group: `Environment=PGOPTS=-i`. I can see the directory is read (and other variables are read - like PGDATA - but it is not reading PGOPTS or at least the postmaster process is not being started with the option); For the sake of it, I also tried setting it in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service` without success;
- `/etc/conf.d/postgresql` but, as I read somewhere, it is not used anymore;
- `/etc/profile.d/postgresql.sh` setting and exporting the variable;
- `~postgres/.bash-profile` setting and exporting the variable;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with systemd *Environment=* settings. (On the other hand, service startup process doesn't involve *anything* like user shells and interactive logins, so "profile" files are absolutely irrelevant.)

But the problem is that the PostgreSQL daemon **doesn't use** and has never used this environment variable in the first place. There is nothing in the actual software that would make the contents of $PGOPTS be magically appended to the daemon's command line.

Said magic used to be done within the old *startup script* (`/etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql` which was used by RedHat/CentOS before systemd) – it isn't actually used as an "environment" variable, but as a direct substitution in the 'postgres' command line:

```
111 # Override defaults from /etc/sysconfig/pgsql if file is present
112 [ -f /etc/sysconfig/pgsql/${NAME} ] && . /etc/sysconfig/pgsql/${NAME}
113
...
178         echo -n "$PSQL_START"
179         $SU -l postgres -c "$PGENGINE/postmaster -p '$PGPORT' -D '$PGDATA' ${PGOPTS} &" >> "$PGLOG" 2>&1 < /dev/null
180         sleep 2
```

---

So where to add the `-i` command line option, if not to $PGOPTS? Add it directly to the 'postgres' command line, of course. The full command line is specified in *ExecStart=* for systemd's postgresql.service; you can see that it still retains *some* substitutions, but you can just as well add custom options directly:

```
ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postmaster -D ${PGDATA}
```

Change this to:

```
ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postmaster -D ${PGDATA} -i
```

Note: do not edit systemd units in /usr/lib; instead, copy the unit file to /etc/systemd/system and edit your copy, so that your changes will not be lost during package upgrades.

---

The postmaster(1) manual page says:

```
DESCRIPTION
    postmaster is a deprecated alias of postgres.
```

Comment: I was trying to isolate the option as much as possible (also because I don't always want this enabled) by simply using the `PGOPTS` env that I thought was still being used. Since you pointed out it isn't used anymore in systemd, I guess I will have to go with alternatives like your suggestion by adding it to the service or having a custom `postgresql.conf` file, changing the `listen_addresses`. Thanks.